# Will there by a voltage drop in the p-type in the diode?

Tags: electricity, semiconductor-physics

Assume we have a pn diode, and we have forward bias so that we get electricity through the diode.

**My question:**

Will there be a voltage drop over the p type? (NOT the depletion laywer, but the rest of the p type)?

Answer (score 0):

No there won't be. This is obvious looking at the band diagram; the only place in the junction with a change in potential is the depletion region:

[image]

Note: In reality the depletion region does not 'start' and 'end', and the diffusion/drift currents are continuous distributions so there is a very small potential across both the N and P; but assuming a discrete depletion region, there is no potential accross P or N region

Comment: There is a resistivity to both the n and p regions, so in a real device, yes, there is a voltage drop between the lead and the junction.